# Форматирование текстового вывода

Tags: python, алгоритм

я совсем недавно начала учить Python. Решила написать программу про пингвинов:какую цифру ты напишешь, столько и будет пингвинов. Но я никак не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы символы из которых будет состоять один пингвин находились в столбике.
Пожалуйста, объясните языком, понятным для чайников :з

```
phrase1 =str('_~_')
phrase2 =str('(o o)')
phrase3 = str('//  V  \\')
phrase4 =str('//(  _  )\\')
phrase5 = str('^^ ^^')
N=int(input())
print ((phrase1, and='', phrase2, and='', phrase3, and='', phrase4, and='', phrase5) * N )
```

Comment: Добить пробелами?

Comment: 1 - str к строкам применять не нужно. Строки они и так строки - сильнее они строками уже не станут. 2 - нужно добить каждую строку пробелами справа и слева, чтобы пингвин стал ровным. 3 - нужно не пытаться формировать кортеж, потом умножать его на N, а каждую часть строки умножать на N, и вместо `and=''` десять раз в конце сделайте `sep='\n'`. 4 - есть целых два таких же вопроса с этими пингвинами.

Comment: Ну ёк-макарёк... Старался, писал развёрнутый ответ, а вопрос взяли и закрыли... Короче выкладываю мой ответ здесь https://pastebin.com/hS4ERdec , раз уж к вопросу не могу прикрепить

Comment: @Xander, ну технически я могу переоткрыть. Но вообще, насколько я понимаю по предыдущим таким вопросам, там пингвины должны идти в строчку.

Comment: Хотя может там разные задания, сначала сделать вертикально, потом горизонтально.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пытаться) -@Xander